# Magnitude of complex number $a=\frac {1-e^{-i\omega L}}{1-e^{-i\omega}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried using $\sqrt{a*a^*}$ but I still got some complex parts...shouldn't the magnitude contain no complex part?

I did:
$a*a^*=\frac {1-e^{-i\omega L}}{1-e^{-i\omega}}\frac {1-e^{i\omega L}}{1-e^{i\omega}}=\frac {2-e^{-i\omega L}-e^{i\omega L}}{2-e^{-i\omega}-e^{i\omega}}$, but don't know how to make the complex parts disappear...

Comment: Are you sure you did the calculation correct?

Comment: updated my work

Comment: I'll check when i get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take half power out from numerator and denominator. So
$$a=\frac{e^{-\frac{iwL}{2}}(e^{\frac{iwL}{2}}-e^{-\frac{iwL}{2}})}{e^{-\frac{iw}{2}}(e^{\frac{iw}{2}}-e^{-\frac{iw}{2}})}=\frac{e^{-\frac{iw(L-1)}{2}}sin(\frac{wL}{2})}{sin(\frac{w}{2})}$$ So magnitude of the $a$ is simply $$|a|=|\frac{sin(\frac{wL}{2})}{sin(\frac{w}{2})}|$$ because $|e^{-\frac{iw(L-1)}{2}}|=1$

which is the final answer

Hope this will be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow on what you already did using $\cos{\theta}=(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2$. We get

$$a\cdot\bar{a}={2(1-\cos{\omega L})\over 2(1-\cos{\omega})}={1-\cos{\omega L}\over1-\cos{\omega}}$$

Now we can go a bit further with some more trigonometry using $\cos{\theta}=1-2\sin^2{\theta/2}$. We get

$$a\cdot\bar{a}={\sin^2{\omega L\over2}\over\sin^2{\omega\over2}}$$