# How do you find the phase of $X(\omega) = \frac{1-e^{-L i\omega}}{1-e^{-i \omega}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842090/magnitude-of-complex-number-a-frac-1-e-i-omega-l1-e-i-omega) perfectly explains how to find the magnitude of

$X(\omega) = \frac{1-e^{-L i\omega}}{1-e^{-i \omega}}$ ?

But how do you find its phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the link you provided, you can rewrite $X$ as
\begin{equation*}
X(\omega) = \frac{\sin(\omega L/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}e^{-i\frac{\omega(L-1)}{2}}.
\end{equation*}
This is now in polar form $X(\omega) = |X(\omega)|e^{i\angle X(\omega)}$, so the phase can be immediately read off as
\begin{equation*}
\angle X(\omega) = -\frac{\omega(L-1)}{2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Damn, that's slick.